# Replace dash with space in username on login

Tags: login, wp-login-form

All my users have usernames that follow this pattern: `firstname-lastname` (with a dash between them).

However, I would like to allow them to login to WP (multisite) with a space instead of a dash.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can, though I've never tried. After digging through `wp-login.php` and a few other files, I found my way to the `sanitize_user` function and filter. Here's the function description from [`/wp-includes/formatting.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php) (on line 888 as of this writing):

> Removes tags, octets, entities, and if strict is enabled, will only keep alphanumeric, _, space, ., -, @. After sanitizing, it passes the username, raw username (the username in the parameter), and the value of $strict as parameters for the 'sanitize_user' filter.

Here's the filter, the last line of the function:

```
apply_filters( 'sanitize_user', $username, $raw_username, $strict );
```

So, you obviously need to take care to appropriately sanitize the username (and probably should account for when `$strict` is `true`), but you can override the username passed onto WordPress from the login form *and* other forms (which is to be say, be careful and watch out for something unexpected).